# How do I fix having nothing but a blinking black screen after installation?

Tags: system-installation

After installing elementary OS I rebooted the PC and saw blinking black screen. I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, but it is not working. Even the flash drive with OS is not working.

Comment: You'll have to provide a ton of information to figure out why this is happening. Did you use a USB drive to boot? What did you use to create the USB drive? Which version of elementary OS (32 or 64-bit) did you put on the USB drive? What are the specs of the target machine? Was the installation successful or are you simply trying to boot to the USB key to install?

Comment: Yes I used USB drive to boot,unetbootin,64-bit, a laptop with Intel core i5,6Gb RAM,GeForce 630M and with Windows 8.Yes,installation was successful,OS asked me to reboot,I click "yes" and then when clicked "Elementary OS" have that issue.

Comment: @RostislavProzorovsky Did you gain any solution to your issue?

Comment: I have the same issue on Loki Beta after a simple update/upgrade. Loki was installed for a month now and was working fine. It still just blink at boot, I can see time to time the mouse but thats it.
Is there a way to rollback?or boot another way ? I am preparing an external drive to try to access the system. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

If you're dual booting, you might need to fully boot into Windows first (I'm just assuming its your primary OS), and do a proper restart into Elementary OS. I got this sometimes with other Linux distros because the disk didn't shut down properly

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me, but the OS was actually installed. Try to boot without the USB drive plugged.

Answer (score -1):

I has same issue yesterday.
I reinstalled but this time didn't select the option to download and install updates during process and it was fine.
I let it update once finished and it was fine. 
Might be worth a try .